# Which structure is best for implementation when the number of elements in a list/array is variable?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, linked-list

I have a slightly specific question. I am using C/C++ with OpenCV. My aim to store detected rectangles in a list/array style structure. However, the length is variable for every frame (iteration).

What should I use to store this info? I thought of Linked Lists, however, they are slow to traverse and also if the number of nodes decrease, I will have to manually delete the extra nodes which would take up even more processor time. I discarded Arrays as they are not very flexible in terms of their length. I can do dynamic arrays with malloc but even with that I think I will need to specify the maximum number of elements.

feel free to correct me if i'm wrong somewhere. Also please do share your views and let me know what you think is the best way to go about this?

Thanks

EDIT: I'm not restricted to C (i know i mentioned malloc). I can use C++ features as well as the rest of my program does not use any C specific functions. So do feel free to suggest me any better ways.

Comment: Removed C++ tag as you said you're using C and referenced malloc, and anyone in C++ would just use a vector.

Comment: @DeadMG: point noted. I did forget to mention that I'm not restricted to C, I can work in C++ and the rest of my program doesn't use C specific functions. So I tagged C++ just to open up more possibilities.  (just edited my post and added back the tag, hope you don't mind)

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you need to store. Are the rectangles just coordinates? Or will you copy image data?

Comment: @kotlinski: in OpenCV there is a type called CvRect. Internally I believe this is a matrix and stores 4 values x, y, height, width. So if I do use malloc/calloc/realloc I would use `sizeof(CvRect)`

Comment: @Atharval: If the structure is so small, I wouldn't worry about wasted memory unless there are millions of rectangles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would recommend you to use `std::vector`. The elements in a `std::vector` are guaranteed by the C++ Standard to be contiguous, just like a C *array* would be. This allows `std::vector` to be the *interface* between C++ data structures and C functions. You can use `std::vector<T>::resize` to make sure there is space allocated before passing it to the OpenCV functions.

Oh, to get a pointer to the internal storage of the vector you typically use this notation: `&rectangleCollection[0]`.

Good luck!

Comment: That's a good thing to do. When you have some experience with them you are welcome to ask more specific questions, that's a great way to learn!

Comment: it looks like a good option except when copying lists. I anticipate later on I will need two lists `prev` and `curr` so I will need to copy the contents of `curr` to `prev`. With pointers that is a lot faster but with vectors I think that involves actually copying all the contents across. so for my application that might be slow for a large number of elements. thanks for the suggestion tho.

Comment: Actually you can swap the contents of two vectors, if you wish. That is a quick operation very similar to using raw pointers.

Comment: Even if you need to copy (insert/append) rather than swap, there are efficient simple ways of doing that with `vector`.

Comment: @Steve: kind of. If you need to do *a lot* of splicing of different sequences, `std::list` might be a better choice. But then you suffer from all the other inefficiencies of a linked list.

Comment: @jalf, agreed, but I would need strong evidence from measurement before using `list` over `deque` or `vector`.  Iterator guarantees are `list`'s only ace in the hole, and it's a devil's bargain.

Answer (score 3):

You can do dynamic arrays and use `realloc()` when it needs to grow. If possible:

- Since your initial array to be (perhaps) the average length you expect
- Use exponential growth, so that when you do reallocate the array, you double the allocated size

Of course, you could also do something more intricate, but I would recommend testing with plain reallocated arrays first.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you would free an extant array of maximum size and then allocate a new array of larger size and assign the original pointer to the new array. Also, there's no need or reason to downsize your array just because you're not filling it, if you know that in the future you may well need more space. It's a waste of performance constantly resizing your data structures to be an exact fit for the data within them.

Edit: Oh, so you ARE actually using C++. In that case, just get a vector.

Comment: so if you allocate a maximum size and only utilise/fill,say,60% of it on avg , does that not mean that you are wasting the rest of the allocated memory? I should also mention i'm looking at quite large sizes and ranges from 1 to 100 or more elements.

Comment: @Athaval: 1 to 100 is not a lot of elements, unless your elements are several MB in size. You are wasting the rest of the allocated memory - but that has to be offset against the peformance waste of constantly re-allocating. Most advanced systems allocate more than necessary, because re-allocating to get the perfect fit is just far too costly.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use vectors because of their flexibility, but are restricted to C, you can easily replicate their behavior using structs and supporting functions. Here is an example definition for a C vector:

```
struct cvector {
  rectangle** array_;
  int size_;
  int allocation_;
};
```

array_ would hold the internal array of pointers to rectangles, size_ would hold the total number of valid rectangles within the vector, and allocation is how much space is allocated for array_ currently. Some example declarations of helper functions you might write to work with this:

```
int cvector_push_back(rectangle* rec);
rectangle* cvector_access(int index);
cvector* cvector_create();
int cvector_free(cvector* cv);
```

If you stick to your interface when accessing it, you should be able to get the same functionality of a vector without much work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends:

Generally I would recommend CGrowableArray found in the DirectX SDK.
(You don't need to include DirectX, just rip out that class template)
(If you don't want to use a C++ class template , you can easily implement the same logic as a bunch of C functions)

What benefit does it have over a std::vector?

a) It allocates objects head of time, using a heuristic

b) You can Reset() it, which will only destroy the contained objects but not free the memory.

Each frame you Reset() the array, then happily add your objects.
You only pay for ctor/dtor calls, but (most times) not for alloc/free calls.

---

On the other hand, if you're not going to store actual objects but pointers, an intrusive linked list is ideal. In that case, both "Append" (2 assignments) and "Clear" (1 assignment) are trivial and no allocation is involved whatsoever. "Remove" is a different story, but given your problem statement you don't seem to have a need for that anyway.